# Click Not to Fire After Selector is Changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events, selector

I have an anchor in the website. When someone clicks on it I do smth in jquery and change name, but when it is clicked again event is fired, despite I've changed it's name.
code here:

```
$(".like_cont a[name=like]").click(function (e) {
                alert("W");
                var t = $(this);

                t.find("img").attr("src", "images/like_icon.png");

                var ls = parseInt(t.next().next()) + 1;
                t.next().next().text(ls);

                var params = "Like|" + t.attr("lik");
                CallServer(params, "");

                t.attr("name", "liked");
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

after Click `name` is **liked** but another click events Fire. How to change selector to preserve firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be to call [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the click event from your object.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.off()` to remove the event handler as per Iridio's answer.

Or you can use a delegated event handling model:

```
$(".like_cont").on("click", "a[name=like]", function (e) {
    ...
});
```

This relies on the fact that click (and most other) events bubble up from the source element through all their containing elements. So with a handler bound with this syntax of `.on()`, whenever a click occurs on (in this example) the `".like_cont"` element(s), jQuery tests the event's source element to see if it matches the selector in the second parameter, `"a[name=like]"` - if it does then the function is called, otherwise it is not.

In other words, with a delegated handling model the function will be called only if the clicked element matches the selector in the second parameter *at the time the event occurs*.

With a "standard" handler bound with `.click()`, or bound with `.on()` *without* that second parameter, the event is bound directly to the element(s) that matched the selector *at the time the event was bound* - regardless of whether such elements still match that selector at the time of the event. (Not that that is a bad thing - sometimes it's exactly what you need, just not in your present case.)